# Using react-router without JSX

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, react-router, reagent

I'm trying to find an example of using react-router through the javascript API but have been unable to find anything so far.

My goal is to use react-router with reagent and clojurescript.  So if anyone has gotten this working (even with Om), I'd appreciate a push in the right direction.  Otherwise, just a straight javascript example without JSX would be helpful.

#### Edit 1 -- Getting closer to a solution

Thanks to @FakeRainBrigand for the help translating the JSX into plain JS.

Here is the React.js 0.11.2 version (which is what the current release of Reagent uses -- 0.4.3).

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
Routes({location: "history"},
       Route({name: "app", path: "/", handler: App},
             Route({name: "inbox", handler: Inbox}),
             Route({name: "calendar", handler: "{Calendar}"})))
```

Hint: You can perform the JSX->JS transformation using `JSXTransformer.js` for your version of React.  Just include it in your page and use your browser's developer console to execute `JSXTransformer.transform('/** @jsx React.DOM */<Route location="history">...</Route>').code`

Here is the Clojurescript version:

```
(ns mytest.core
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]])

(defn home []
  [:div [:h1 "Home Component Placeholder"]])

(defn info []
  [:div [:h1 "Info Component Placeholder"]])

(defn build-component [comp]
  (reagent/as-component (if (fn? comp) (comp) comp)))

(defn react-router []
  (js/ReactRouter.Routes #js {:location "history"}
                         (js/ReactRouter.Route #js {:name "app" :path "/" :handler (build-component home)}
                                               (js/ReactRouter.DefaultRoute #js {:handler (build-component home)})
                                               (js/ReactRouter.Route #js {:name "about" :path "/about" :handler (build-component info)}))))
```

Unfortunately, the components Reagent creates by default don't seem to be "standard" React components, in that `React.isValidClass(myReagentComponent) === false`.  So all that is left is to figure out how to generate the components in the form that passes that test.  I have a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770117/reagent-generate-a-react-component-that-passes-react-isvalidclasscomponent) posted for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 0.12 in JavaScript it looks like this:

```js
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = React.createFactory(Router.Route);
var DefaultRoute = React.createFactory(Router.DefaultRoute);
var NotFoundRoute = React.createFactory(Router.NotFoundRoute);

React.render((
  React.createElement(Router, {location: "history"}, 
    Route({path: "/", handler: App}, 
      DefaultRoute({handler: Home}), 
      Route({name: "about", handler: About}), 
      Route({name: "users", handler: Users}, 
        Route({name: "recent-users", path: "recent", handler: RecentUsers}), 
        Route({name: "user", path: "/user/:userId", handler: User}), 
        NotFoundRoute({handler: UserRouteNotFound})
      )
    ), 
    NotFoundRoute({handler: NotFound})
  )
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 5):

An example without JX and without using `createElement` (which doesn't make sense to me in case of routes):

```
// this snippet was tested with react 0.13.1 
// and react-router 0.13.2
import Router from 'react-router';
import App    from './components/App';
import Inbox  from './components/Inbox';

const AppRoute = Router.createRoute({
  path: '/',
  name: 'app',
  handler: App
});

const InboxRoute = Router.createRoute({
  name: 'inbox',
  handler: Inbox,
  parentRoute: AppRoute
});

// Important: you have to export the root route wrapped in array 
export default [AppRoute];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just finished putting together an experiment repository for doing this
https://github.com/ghedamat/reagent-react-router

The main idea is using the new apis that Reagent provides since version 0.5.0-alpha3 for interop with React

`reagent/reactify-component` let's you use reagent components in React code (which is what the router requires)

and `reagent/adapt-react-class` enables the vice-versa.

What I'm attempting to do is wrap Components like `Link` and `RouterHandler` and use them directly in reagent.

i.e:

```
[:ul.nav.navbar-nav
  [:li
    [Link {:to "app"} "home"]]
  [:li
    [Link {:to "about"} "about page"]]]
```

Conversely you can pass Reagent's components as `handlers` to the `ReactRouter.Router` object.

```
(def routes
  (Route {:name "app" :path "/" :handler app-page}
    (Route {:name "about" :path "about" :handler about-page}))
  (DefaultRoute {:handler default-page-meta})))
```

The implementation is quite simple (and similar to your updated question): https://github.com/ghedamat/reagent-react-router/blob/master/src/cljs/reagent_react_router/react_router.cljs
Look at the README for a more in-depth discussion.

It's working so far but could definitely use more inputs/help.