# Reagent generate a React Component that passes React.isValidClass(component)?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, react-router, reagent

I'm trying to use react-router in my Clojurescript Reagent project.  The problem is, react-router requires that components pass `React.isValidClass(component)`, which in React 0.11.2 is defined as:

```
ReactDescriptor.isValidFactory = function(factory) {
  return typeof factory === 'function' &&
         factory.prototype instanceof ReactDescriptor;
};
```

Reagent seems to generate components as an object instead of a function.  Here is my code:

```
(defn home []
  [:div [:h1 "Home Page placeholder"]])

(reagent/as-component (home)) ; => #<[object Object]>
```

Has anyone worked out how to make this sort of interop work?

Comment: i found an attempt to do the same on github: https://github.com/ghedamat/reagent-react-router, may be it helps.

Answer (score 1):

What [reagent-react-router](https://github.com/ghedamat/reagent-react-router) does to make this work is use `reagent.core/reactify-component`. The `reactify-component` exists to make Reagent components valid React components for these kinds of inter-op scenarios.